# How to get a callback when Leaflet markercluster has finished drawing the layer / map?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

in order to stop a spinner / progress bar I need to get informed by Leaflet markercluster when the layer/map is finished drawing the marker & cluster (and nothing happens anymore on the map).

I've tried it with `map.moveend` which fires before markercluster is finished and with `markercluster.animationend` but this only handles individual cluster animations.

Is there any event in Leaflet's map or markercluster that fired at or near the end of drawing the markers on the map?

PS: I'm using `react-leaflet` with `react-leaflet-markercluster`

Comment: What if you put all the cluster in a `MarkerClusterGroup` and [call `animationend` on the group](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#additional-markerclustergroup-events)?